# Django 1.8 conditional annotation results in INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.8

The models:

```
class Bar(GenericModel):
    ...

class Foo(GenericModel):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='foo_bar')
```

The query:

```
bars = Bar.objects
       .prefetch_related('foo_bar')
       .annotate(sum_foo=Sum(
                             Case(
                                  When(foo_bar__is_deleted=False, then='foo_bar__amount'),
                                  default=Value(0),
                                  output_field=IntegerField()
                                 )
                            )
                )
```

The former results in an inner join: `SELECT ... FROM "bar" INNER JOIN "foo" ON ( "bar"."id" = "foo"."bar_id" ) ...`

What I intend to obtain is a LEFT OUTER JOIN (a full list of "bar" objects annotated with "foo.amount" sums, or 0s if "foo" related to "bar" doesn't exist) instead of the INNER JOIN? Is it possible to do without falling back to raw SQL?

Comment: As a note to people in the future. This was probably caused by a bug that was fixed in 1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way seems to work correctly:

```
bars = Bar.objects
       .prefetch_related('foo_bar')
       .annotate(sum_foo=Sum(
                             Case(
                                  When(Q(foo_bar__is_deleted=False) | Q(foo_bar__is_deleted=None),
                                                 then='foo_bar__amount'),
                                  default=Value(0),
                                  output_field=IntegerField()
                                 )
                            ),
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24924), corrected in Django 1.8.3 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8.3/)).

As you noted, the issue is that an `INNER JOIN` is being created, filtering out `Bar` objects when there's no corresponding relation to `Foo` objects.

Using a Django version higher than 1.8.3 will solve the issue.