# Django query with annotated conditional expression uses INNER JOIN. How do I get it to use OUTER JOIN?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.8

I have a "Meal" model with a foreign key to "Food". Each meal has a rating: good, bad, or indifferent. I want to query a list of all foods and annotate the count of each type of meal rating, but some foods have no meals yet, so I want the query to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and in that case the counts should be zero.

I am using Conditional Expressions in Django 1.8, and it always switches the relationship to an INNER JOIN between "Food" and "Meal". For example:

Meal model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    GOOD = 1
    BAD = 2
    INDIFFERENT = 3
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (GOOD, 'Good'),
        (BAD, 'Bad'),
        (INDIFFERENT, 'Indifferent')
    )
    meal_time = models.DateTimeField()
    food = models.ForeignKey("Food")
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

When I query `Food.objects.annotate(total_meals=Count('meal'))`, Django generates a query like

```
SELECT ... FROM "Food" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Meal" ON ... 
GROUP BY "Food"
```

However, when I add these conditional annotations:

```
class FoodQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_meal_rating_frequency(self):
        return self.annotate(
            total_meals=Count('meal'),
            good_meals=Sum(
                 Case(When(meal__rating=Meal.GOOD, then=1),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=0)
            ),
            bad_meals=Sum(
                Case(When(meal__rating=Meal.BAD, then=1),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=0)
            ),
            indifferent_meals=Sum(
                Case(When(meal__rating=Meal.INDIFFERENT, then=1),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=0)
            )
        )
```

Django uses and `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT ... FROM "Food"
INNER JOIN "Meal" ON ...
GROUP BY "Food"
```

I know this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282502/django-1-8-conditional-annotation-results-in-inner-join-instead-of-left-outer-jo) but Its not clear to me how to apply the accepted solution to my case. How can I get Django to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN? Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that seems to be working so far, using `Count()` instead of `Sum()` and having the conditions check for NULL meals, which won't be included in the count:

```
class FoodQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_meal_rating_frequency(self):
        return self.annotate(
            total_meals=Count('meal'),
            good_meals=Count(
                Case(When(Q(meal__isnull=True) | Q(meal__rating=Meal.GOOD), then='meal__rating'),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=None)
            ),
            bad_meals=Count(
                Case(When(Q(meal__isnull=True) | Q(meal__rating=Meal.BAD), then='meal__rating'),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=None)
            ),
            indifferent_meals=Count(
                Case(When(Q(meal__isnull=True) | Q(meal__rating=Meal.INDIFFERENT), then='meal__rating'),
                    output_field=models.IntegerField(), default=None)
            )
        )
```